# Meteor methods wait before execution on client proceeds

Tags: meteor

could anybody please tell me how to make clients wait until the called function on the server is executed?

My code:

```
Meteor.methods({
markLettersAsRead: function(userId) {
    if(serverVar) {
        Users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: {letters: []}}); // removing all references
    }
}
```

});

```
Template.letter.events({
'click a': function() {
    Meteor.call('markLettersAsRead', Meteor.userId(), this._id, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    var usersExistsWithThisLetter = Users.find({letters: {_id: this._id}}).count();
    console.log(usersExistsWithThisLetter);
}
```

});

In my example `usersExistsWithThisLetter` is always 1 because the `Users.find()` doesn't wait until the `Meteor.call` is done. I verified this by checking the database and no users exists with entries in the `letters` array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query the collection inside the callback, because then you can be certain that your server method has already been executed. I would do something like this (note the `self` variable declaration):

```
var self = this;
Meteor.call('markLettersAsRead', Meteor.userId(), this._id, function(err) {
   if (!err) {
       var usersExistsWithThisLetter = Users.find({letters: {_id: self._id}}).count();
       console.log(usersExistsWithThisLetter);                
   } else {
       console.log(err);
   }
});
```

I hope it helps!